# If a graph G contains subdivision of H as graphs then H is a minor

Tags: graph-theory

Let H be a graph with maximum degree 3. Prove that a graph G contains H as
a minor if and only if G contains a subdivision of H as a subgraph.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. please refer to [how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands, your question lacks context and will likely be closed. Can you explain where the question comes from? what have you tried?

Comment: here you can see the full problem https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uGHp5nJKiNKuKloP9QzPqoAga0es8Bhm/view?usp=sharing